# Python lists intersection/comparison with (two) loops

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have 4 lists of values (various characters and strings): for example lista, listb, listc and listd.
Three of these four lists are long and equal in length. I used them in a ”for” loop with zip() to build new strings.

```
lista =\
        [
                u"aaa1",
                u"aaa2",
                u"a 500",
        ]

listb =\
        [
                u"ba1",
                u"ba2",
                u"baâ\"500",
        ]

listc =\
        [
                u"c1",
                u"c2",
                u"c500",
        ]

listd =\
        [
                u"aaa1",
                u"a 500",
        ]

for a, b, c, in zip(lista, listb, listc):
      do something with a,b and c
```

The fourth list (listd) is shorter and it contains elements from one of these 3 lists (lista), but not only.

Now I have to iterate through the fourth list comparing it's elements with those from first list and when elements are equal then do my previous iteration with it's function. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: I'm confused as to what it is you're trying to do.... Could you give sample output?

Comment: Also: please follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when writing code. This doesn't even look like Python as-is! It should look something more like: https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/a7825bbb03be32e1f135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what you mean; what about:

```
for a, b, c in zip(lista, listb, listc):
    if a in listd:
        do something with a, b, and c
```

Comment: I think this is the closest we can get from the question text as-written. Hopefully OP will come and clarify his intent.